# How can I filter data with an 'int64' type column?

Tags: mysql, datetime, go, go-gorm

I get lots of data and serialize them to a struct with a field 'Create_time' of type Int64, such as:

```
type Log struct {
    ID            int       `mapstructure:"id"`
    Create_time   int64     `mapstructure:"create_time,omitempty"`
}
```

Now if I want to filter data between 2021-10-24 00:00:00 and 2021-10-25 00:00:00, how can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `Create_time` is obtained using `Time.Unix()`, you can find the `Unix` representation for the range, and then filter:

```
from:=time.Date(2021,10,24,0,0,0,0,time.Local).Unix()
to:=time.Date(2021,10,25,0,0,0,0,time.Local).Unix()
```

Then find all elements with `Create_time>=from && Create_time<=to`.

Make the necessary changes about the timezones. If the `Create_time` is milli/micro/nanoseconds, then use `UnixMilli`, `UnixMicro`, or `UnixNano`.